# SQL query the largest and smallest amount

Tags: sql, max, min

I have a table `Sales` with the following fields: `code, amount, index, name`.

I need to get the smallest and the largest `amount` for a given `name`, and the `code` for which the amount is the smallest and largest.

Can somebody help me in constructing a query?

Comment: No.. it's Foxbase. I've got a query: select (select code from Sale z1 where amount = (select max(amount) from Sale z2 where z2.name = z3.name)), in from Sale z3 but it's doesn't work properly. it's displaying a message 'error correlating fields'

Comment: @BKl: Wait, Foxbase, the '80s-era X-base clone?  Or something else?  Can you clarify, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find min and max amount per name:

```
select
   name
   min(amount), max(amount)
from
  sales
group by name
```

and to get both(min and max) and code in single query:

```
select *
from sales s
where 
       (amount = (select
                   max(s1.amount)
                 from sales s1
                 where  s1.name = s.name)
        or
        amount = (select
                   min(s2.amount)
                 from sales s2
                 where  s2.name = s.name)
       )
```

Comment: ok, but i wanna it in one query, and for all fields 'name' could you tell me how I can join it? i have tried using outer join, but it wasn't work good for me

Comment: if you want for all values of 'name' you can safely remove the condition `name = 'given_name'`

Comment: @BKl I've updated my response. Do you want to add a query over all values of 'name'?

Comment: i've got sth like this: select (select code from Sale z1 where amount = (select max(amount) from Sale z2 where z2.name = z3.name)), in from Sale z3 but it's doesn't work properly. it's displaying a message 'error correlating fields'. could you help me to fix that query?

Comment: it had some problems. Can you try this. I don't know if this works on your database: `select 
  (select 
     code 
   from 
     Sale z1 
   where 
     amount = (select 
                       max(amount) 
                     from Sale z2 
                     where z2.name = z3.name)
    ) from Sale z3`

Comment: Now I undestand what you want. I'll update my answer in seconds.

Comment: It's displaying a a message 'error correlationg fields' too. I've got old database... Foxbase with tabels putting in dbf files.

Comment: Your query is working very well! Thanks for your help. It's the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 4):

If CTE and row_number() is available to you.

```
with S as 
(
  select Amount,
         Code,
         row_number() over(order by Amount asc) as rn1,
         row_number() over(order by Amount desc) as rn2
  from Sales
  where Name = 'SomeName'       
)
select SMin.Amount as MinAmount,
       SMin.Code as MinCode,
       SMax.Amount as MaxAmount,
       SMax.Code as MaxCode
from S as SMin
  cross join S as SMax
where SMin.rn1 = 1 and
      SMax.rn2 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Postgres, try the following:

```
select name, 
       amount, 
       code,
       case when min_rank=max_rank then 'Minimum and Maximum'
            when min_rank=1 then 'Minimum'
            else 'Maximum'
       end as min_or_max
from
(select s.*,
        rank() over (partition by name order by amount) min_rank,
        rank() over (partition by name order by amount desc) max_rank
 from sales s) v
where 1 in (min_rank, max_rank)
```